# How do I add a memory to a MultiQueryRetriever in a SequentialChain?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to create a chatbot that have knowledge on the data save in pinecone using streamlit. I can already ask questions and get answers but I am having a hard time setting up its memory for it to add the context of my previous messages.

Here is some part of my code

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
pinecone.init(api_key=os.environ.get('PINECONE_API_KEY'), environment=os.environ.get('PINECONE_ENV'))
vectorstore = Pinecone.from_existing_index(index_name, embeddings)
llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.9, model_name = "gpt-4-0125-preview", max_tokens=4000)
retriever = MultiQueryRetriever.from_llm(
retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(), llm=llm
)
user_prompt = st.chat_input()

QA_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["query", "contexts","chat_history"],
    template="""You are a professional grant proposal writer. Your task is to create grant proposal content
    for a particular grant proposal topic that the user wants. You can use the context provided to make the grant proposal content
    detailed, comprehensive and accurate. If the question or queries cannot be answered using the information
    provided say use your own knowledge to answer the query.

    chat_history: {chat_history}
    Contexts:
    {contexts}

    Question: {query}
    AI:"""
    )   
memory = ConversationSummaryBufferMemory(
    llm=llm,
    memory_key="chat_history",
    input_key="query",
    max_token=5000 # after 5000 token, summary of the conversation will be created and stored in moving_summary_buffer
    )
qa_chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm, chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=QA_PROMPT)

def retrieval_transform(inputs: dict) -> dict:
    docs = retriever.get_relevant_documents(query=inputs["user_prompt"])
    docs = [d.page_content for d in docs]
    docs_dict = {
        "query": inputs["user_prompt"],
        "contexts": "\n---\n".join(docs)
    }
    return docs_dict

retrieval_chain = TransformChain(
    input_variables=["user_prompt"],
    output_variables=["query", "contexts"],
    transform=retrieval_transform
)

rag_chain = SequentialChain(
    chains=[retrieval_chain, qa_chain],
    input_variables=["user_prompt"],  # we need to name differently to output "query"
    output_variables=["query", "contexts", "text"],
    verbose=True
)
if "messages" not in st.session_state.keys():
    st.session_state.messages = [
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "Hello there, enter your question for grant proposal assistance."}
    ]
if "requests" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["requests"] = []
if "responses" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["responses"] = []

for message in st.session_state.messages:
    with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
        st.write(message["content"])

if user_prompt is not None:
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": user_prompt})
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.write(user_prompt)

if st.session_state.messages[-1]["role"] != "assistant":
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        with st.spinner("Thinking..."):
            out = rag_chain({"user_prompt": user_prompt,
                             "contexts": docs_dict["contexts"]})
            ai_response = out["text"]
            st.write(ai_response)
            st.session_state["messages"].append({"role": "assistant", "content": ai_response})
```

I try incorporating memory to the load_qa_chain but i am egetting input_variable error